# Make restricted videos usable by video player

Tags: html, .htaccess

I have a bunch of .mp4 videos on my website.  I was attempting to make it so they could not be accessed via people going to their absolute locations on my website.

I don't want people to be able to navigate to http://mysite.com/video/some_video.mp4 and download my videos.

I modded my .htaccess to restrict .mp4 from being seen.

`<Files ~ "\.mp4$">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>`

This works however, it also disables the video from playing inside of my player.

Is there any way to restrict access to the .mp4 files inside of a certain directory while still enabling my scripts (video player) to access them?

Any input is appreciated, thanks!

**Fixed**
I was able to get this working finally! Thanks RussellHarrower!

Here is what my .htaccess looks like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?domain\.net/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://domain.net/404 [L]
<Files .mp4>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from my_servers_ip_address
#allow from env=internal
</Files>
```

Comment: Try checking for a referrer. You could do a reverse-anti-hotlink sort of thing, where you only serve the request if there *was* a referrer.

Comment: @WaleedKhan carfeful because many UAs have privacy features that disable the `referrer` header in all circumstances. Software like Norton Internet Security does this too.

Comment: you will also need to get the IP address your server, as this will allow your player as long as it is on the same server to play the video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to do this as well, But this is as close as I have gotten

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERRER} !=http://(.*).domain.com/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/index.html
<Files .*>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 123.119.141.11
Allow from 127.0.0.1
#allow from env=internal
</Files>
```

However it seems to STOP all videos playing even when coming from the correct http referrer

**UPDATE2**

A better way to do it is by the following - this is not a perfect solutions as someone could fake the referrer

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?YOURDOMAIN\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://new.YOURDOMAIN.com/404 [L]
```

That is what is working for me.

Comment: This is blocking the videos but unfortunately still not allowing my player to play the a video. Why do you have two IP Addresses listed?

Comment: one is local, 127.0.0.1 and the other is my server IP address make sure uyou change the first one to your server IP address. NOTE: shared servers will allow anyone also on that server to access your stuff

Comment: Still having issues. It is blocking and redirecting to my 404 page, but it is also causing the video to not load.

Comment: can you give me a link to the video page. so I can take a look with my network tools we use here.

Comment: I can tell you this works cos we are creating a Social Networking site that is based on HTML5 video player

Comment: I got it working! I updated my question with the solution. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

[RussellHarrower's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12924823/10251345) works like a charm. Following it up:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://localhost:8888/application/.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.localhost:8888/application/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .(mp4|mp3|avi)$ - [F]
```

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26384990)

Comment: I would, But i do not have sufficient reputations. It requires 15 for up voting.